# How to trim textarea and prevent the form to be sent with whitespaces only Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this `Field`:

```
<div className="my-data-field question-field">
            <Field type="text"
                as="textarea"
                name="question"
                className={props.errors.question && props.touched.question ? "question-field invalid" : "question-field"}
                placeholder={translate["askYourQuestion"]} />
            <ErrorMessage name="question" component="div" className="invalid-field-message" />
        </div>
```

It has validation for empty. The problem is the form can be submited even if I place few whitespaces.

**EDIT**
These are the validation rules:

```
export const validateRequiredFields = (values, requiredFields) =>{
    return requiredFields
    .filter(x => !values[x])
    .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: translate["requiredField"] }), {})
    }
```

Comment: Replace `.filter(x => !values[x])` by `.filter(x => !values[x].trim())` or `.filter(x => values[x].match(/^\s*$/))`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div className="my-data-field question-field">
    <Field type="text"
        validate={validateFunction}
        as="textarea"
        name="question"
        className={props.errors.question && props.touched.question ? "question-field invalid" : "question-field"}
        placeholder={translate["askYourQuestion"]} />
    <ErrorMessage name="question" component="div" className="invalid-field-message" />
</div>
```

```
let validateFunction = value => {
  if(String(value).trim() === "") return "Type something in!"
}
```